# jQuery event binding with .on()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Can someone explain to me why this works:

```
parentBox.on('click', '.close', function() {
   parentBox.fadeOut();                  
   return false; 
 });
```

But this does not:

```
var closeBox = $('.close');
parentBox.on('click', closeBox, function() {
   parentBox.fadeOut();
   return false; 
});
```

When caching `'.close'` into a `var`, no matter where I click in the parent element, it fades out as if the event handler was attached to `parentBox` rather than `'.close'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This not works because

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
```

second parameter is always **selector** (string type), if you need to bind to specific objects use

```
 closeBox.bind('click',function(){/* code here */})
```